# Create a query to get data for unmatched records in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables `t1,t2` as below:

t1

```
[date]      col1  col3  col4
13-05-2020   xyz   ttx  1
16-05-2020   xyz   abc  5
15-05-2019   xyz   abc  2
11-05-2019   xyz   ttx  3
19-05-2020   xyx   abc  4
```

t2

```
[date]          col1
14-05-2019      ttx 
18-05-2020      abc
19-05-2020      abc
```

I am trying to match the `t2` records with `t1` table.if it get matched then matched records should return.
if it not matched then we need to check the prior available date in `t1` and update `t2` with matched date.
if there are no matching record or null it should throw an exception.

matching criteria are `date` and `col1` of `t2` respective to `date` and `col3` of `t1`

expected output

```
[date]          col1
11-05-2019      ttx
16-05-2020      abc
19-05-2020      abc
```

i am trying by getting unmatched record in a temp table and then loop through to get prior date  available in `t1` but stuck with the logic.any hints how we can achieve it?

```
create table #temp(
Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
[date] DATE,
col1 varchar(3)
)

INSERT   INTO #temp
SELECT [date],col1
FROM t2
WHERE [date] NOT IN
    (SELECT [date] 
     FROM t1)
     AND col1 NOT IN(SELECT col3
     FROM t1)


DECLARE @count INT;
DECLARE @id INT=1;
SELECT @count=COUNT(*) FROM #temp
DECLARE @tempdate DATE;

WHILE (@count >0 )
BEGIN
SELECT @tempdate=date FROM #temp WHERE Id=@id

WHILE   --
--logic to get the matched date record

SET @count=@count-1
SET @id=@id+1
END
```

Comment: I am unclear if you want an update or insert.  Please clarify the results that you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff actually i need the matched record if matching else need updated date where it is matching with prior date in t1. updated the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script to prepare data:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  [date] datetime,
  col1 varchar(50),
  col3 varchar(50),
  col4 numeric(18,6)
);

CREATE TABLE t2 (
  [date] datetime,
  col1 varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO t1 ([date], col1, col3, col4) VALUES ('2020-05-12', 'xyz', 'ttx',  1)
INSERT INTO t1 ([date], col1, col3, col4) VALUES ('2020-05-16', 'xyz', 'abc',  5)
INSERT INTO t1 ([date], col1, col3, col4) VALUES ('2019-05-15', 'xyz', 'abc',  2)
INSERT INTO t1 ([date], col1, col3, col4) VALUES ('2019-05-11', 'xyz', 'ttx',  3)
INSERT INTO t1 ([date], col1, col3, col4) VALUES ('2020-05-19', 'xyx', 'abc',  4)


INSERT INTO t2 ([date], col1) VALUES ('2020-05-14', 'ttx')
INSERT INTO t2 ([date], col1) VALUES ('2020-05-18', 'abc')
INSERT INTO t2 ([date], col1) VALUES ('2020-05-19', 'abc')
```

First of all, lets select the desired output:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT TOP 1 t1.[date]
     FROM t1
    WHERE t1.col3 = t2.col1
      AND t2.[date] >= t1.[date]
    ORDER BY 1 DESC) [date],
  t2.col1
FROM t2
```

Explanation: we select rows from t2 and date from matching record in t1, we limited it by `[date]` condition (`t2.[date] >= t1.[date]`), so we get the matching date or the prior available date, like you requested.

The very same could be done using OUTER APPLY

```
SELECT t1_.[date], t2.col1
  FROM t2
  OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 t1.[date]
                 FROM t1 WHERE t1.col3 = t2.col1
                           AND t2.[date] >= t1.[date]
                ORDER BY 1 DESC) t1_
```

NOTE: you have to deal with NULL values, it is not clear what to do.
Options could be: ignore, or use them to delete records in t2 - it is up to you how to use it.

Now, as for updates - the OUTER APPLY form of query is more useful here - basing on it you could write:

```
UPDATE t2
   SET [date] = t1_.[date]
  FROM t2
  OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 t1.[date]
                 FROM t1 WHERE t1.col3 = t2.col1
                          AND t2.[date] >= t1.[date]
                ORDER BY 1 DESC) t1_
```

Again, be careful with nulls.  You might replace OUTER APPLY to CROSS APPLY and that would IGNORE nulls (not update rows in t2, if there is NO matching record, even for prior date).

If you want to check for nulls and raised an error, put this at the begin of your script:

```
IF EXISTS (
     SELECT 1
       FROM t2
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                  SELECT 1
                    FROM t1
                   WHERE t2.[date] >= t1.[date]
                     AND t1.col3 = t2.col1
                )
           )
  RAISERROR (N'No value in t2, which match date or prior date in t1', 16, 1)
```

You could debug the output on your data by using

```
 SELECT *
   FROM t2
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
             SELECT 1
               FROM t1
              WHERE t2.[date] >= t1.[date]
                AND t1.col3 = t2.col1
           )
      )
```

Comment: Great :) Yes you are correct regarding  nulls, if there is null or no matching records.ideally it should through an exception.can we do it here.i have updated the question? Thanks!

Comment: Would this work for you?
```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t2
                   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t1
                                                         WHERE t2.[date] >= t1.[date]
                                                         AND t1.col3 = t2.col1))
  RAISERROR (N'No value in t2, which match date or prior date in t1', 16, 1)
```
I updated my answer - see at the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to match the t2 records with t1 table.if it get matched then matched records should return. if it not matched then we need to check the prior available date in t1 and update t2 with matched date.

Is this what you want?

```
select t2.*, t1.date as new_date
from t2 outer apply
     (select top (1) t1.*
      from t1
      where t1.col3 = t2.col3 and t1.date <= t2.date
      order by t1.date desc
     ) t1;
```

If you want an `update`, then:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t2.*, t1.date as new_date
      from t2 outer apply
           (select top (1) t1.*
            from t1
            where t1.col3 = t2.col3 and t1.date <= t2.date
            order by t1.date desc
           ) t1
     )
update toupdate
     set date = new_date
     where new_date <> date;
```